# difference between a column vector and a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, vector

Goodmorning to all,
I have a column vector

```
vec=np.array([15.1,7.9,4.5,12.8,10.5],ndmin = 2)
```

and a matrix

```
mt = np.matrix([[1,35.5,1.23],[1,40.8,1.89],[1,30.2,1.55],[1,4.3,1.18], [1,10.7,1.68]])
```

if I try to subtract the vectore and the matrix
like

```
 np.subtract(vec,mt)
```

the result is mathematically wrong:

```
array([[ 14.1 , -20.4 ,  13.87],
       [  6.9 , -32.9 ,   6.01],
       [  3.5 , -25.7 ,   2.95],
       [ 11.8 ,   8.5 ,  11.62],
       [  9.5 ,  -0.2 ,   8.82]])
```

all mt's columns' values are subtracted, instead of just the first
I'd like to get this result

```
array([[ 14.1  , 35.5 ,  1.23],
       [ 6.9  , 40.8 ,  1.89],
       [ 3.5  , 30.2 ,  1.55],
       [ 11.8  ,  4.3 ,  1.18],
       [ 9.5  , 10.7 ,  1.68]])
```

how can I fix that? 
thanks to all :)

Comment: `vec_mt = np.substract(vec,mt[0])`?

Comment: thanks to all for the replies. I add that is easily possible to do that with Pandas.
vec=pd.Series([15.1,7.9,4.5,12.8,10.5])
SeG=pd.DataFrame({'const':[1,1,1,1,1], 'growth':[35.5, 40.8, 30.2, 4.3, 10.7], 'dim':[1.23, 1.89, 1.55, 1.18, 1.68]})
a['const']=vec-a['const']

Comment: Are you sure `np.subtract(vec,mt)` ran?  It raises an error for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice and subtract -

- [T](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.5.x/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy.ndarray.T) attribute is the transpose of the array.

**Ex.**

```
import numpy as np

vec=np.array([15.1,7.9,4.5,12.8,10.5],ndmin = 2)
mt = np.matrix([[1,35.5,1.23],[1,40.8,1.89],[1,30.2,1.55],[1,4.3,1.18], [1,10.7,1.68]])

mt[..., 0] = vec.T - mt[..., 0]
#or
#mt.T[0] = np.subtract(vec, mt.T[0])

print(mt)
```

**O/P:**

```
[[14.1  35.5   1.23]
 [ 6.9  40.8   1.89]
 [ 3.5  30.2   1.55]
 [11.8   4.3   1.18]
 [ 9.5  10.7   1.68]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You commented that the `pandas` version is easy.  So is the `numpy` one, if you use the right starting point.

```
In [110]: vec=pd.Series([15.1,7.9,4.5,12.8,10.5]) 
     ...: SeG=pd.DataFrame({'const':[1,1,1,1,1], 'growth':[35.5, 40.8, 30.2, 4.3, 10.7], 'dim':[1.23, 1.89, 1
     ...: .55, 1.18, 1.68]})                                                                                 
In [111]: vec                                                                                                
Out[111]: 
0    15.1
1     7.9
2     4.5
3    12.8
4    10.5
dtype: float64
In [112]: SeG                                                                                                
Out[112]: 
   const  growth   dim
0      1    35.5  1.23
1      1    40.8  1.89
2      1    30.2  1.55
3      1     4.3  1.18
4      1    10.7  1.68
```

`vec` is a Series, its `values` is a 1d array.  Same for one column of `SeG`:

```
In [113]: vec.values                                                                                         
Out[113]: array([15.1,  7.9,  4.5, 12.8, 10.5])
In [114]: SeG['const']                                                                                       
Out[114]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
Name: const, dtype: int64
In [115]: SeG['const'].values                                                                                
Out[115]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

So `a['const']=vec-a['const']` amounts to subtracting one 1d array from another and putting the result back in the right place.  That's exactly what the accepted answer does:

```
mt[..., 0] = vec.T - mt[..., 0]
```

Lets start with 2 arrays, one is 1d, the other 2d (but not the `np.matrix` subclass):

```
In [116]: x=np.array([15.1,7.9,4.5,12.8,10.5])                                                               
In [117]: y = np.array([[1,35.5,1.23],[1,40.8,1.89],[1,30.2,1.55],[1,4.3,1.18], [1,10.7,1.68]])

In [118]: y[:,0] = x - y[:,0]                                                                                
In [119]: y                                                                                                  
Out[119]: 
array([[14.1 , 35.5 ,  1.23],
       [ 6.9 , 40.8 ,  1.89],
       [ 3.5 , 30.2 ,  1.55],
       [11.8 ,  4.3 ,  1.18],
       [ 9.5 , 10.7 ,  1.68]])
```

===

With your original arrays:

```
In [103]: vec                                                                                                
Out[103]: array([[15.1,  7.9,  4.5, 12.8, 10.5]])  # (1,5) shape
In [104]: mt                                                                                                 
Out[104]: 
matrix([[ 1.  , 35.5 ,  1.23],
        [ 1.  , 40.8 ,  1.89],
        [ 1.  , 30.2 ,  1.55],
        [ 1.  ,  4.3 ,  1.18],
        [ 1.  , 10.7 ,  1.68]])     # (5,3) shape
In [105]: vec.T                                                                                              
Out[105]: 
array([[15.1],
       [ 7.9],
       [ 4.5],
       [12.8],
       [10.5]])           # (5,1) shape
In [106]: mt[:,0]                                                                                            
Out[106]: 
matrix([[1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.]])            # (5,1) shape
```

If `mt` as `ndarray` instead of `matrix`, `mt[:,0]` would have a (5,) shape.  That distinction is important.

```
In [107]: mt[:,0] = vec.T-mt[:,0]          # operation on (5,1) arrays
```

Your `subtract(vec, mt)` should have given you an error, not just an undesired result.  `vec` is (1,5) shape, `mt` is (5,3).  Those aren't compatible:

```
In [122]: np.subtract(_103, _104)                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-122-35bafa7d9625> in <module>
----> 1 np.subtract(_103, _104)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,5) (5,3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. Yes, I noticed that ndarray instead of matrix matters for the shape because when I was trying some commands it raised the error you posted.